# How can I set expire time of queue message using ActiveMQ by Java Programming?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

> In this code, I am using setJMSExpiration(1000) for expire message of one second in queue from publisher side. But From Consumer Side, It is returning properly message after 1 second instead of null.

```
        public class RegistrationPublisher extends Thread{
            public void run() {
                publisherQueue("Registration.Main.*");
            }

            public void publisherQueue(String server){
                try {
                    String url="tcp://192.168.20.49:61616";
                    // Create a ConnectionFactory
                    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);

                    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
                    connection.start();

                    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

                    Destination destination = session.createQueue(server);

                    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
                    producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);

                    String text = "Test";
                    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(text);

                    message.setJMSExpiration(1000);// For Expire message in one second


        producer.send(message);


                    producer.close();
                    session.close();
                    connection.close();

                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

                RegistrationPublisher registrationPublisher=new RegistrationPublisher();
                registrationPublisher.start();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You do this by configuring the JMS MessageProducer to do it for you via the send method that accepts a TTL or by calling setTimeToLive on the producer which adds the same TTL to all sent messages.  The JMS APIs for the message version are clear that calling the setters on the message have no effect.

> void setJMSExpiration(long expiration) throws JMSException
>
> Sets the message's expiration value.
>
> This method is for use by JMS providers only to set this field when a message is sent. This message cannot be used by clients to configure the expiration time of the message. This method is public to allow a JMS provider to set this field when sending a message whose implementation is not its own.

Comment: I used "void setJMSExpiration(long expiration) throws JMSException" with extends org.apache.activemq.command.Message and implements javax.jsm.Message but it is not working for expire message. I used method is following:

public void setJMSExpiration(long arg0) throws JMSException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  this.setExpiration(arg0);// TTL is not working here and setExpiration(arg0) is also not working
 }

Comment: Read the answer, and the JMS API.  You cannot call setJMSExpiration and expect anything to happen, just doesn't work.

Comment: I read and implemented everything like "setJMSExpration, setTimeToLive and setExpiration"  according to documentation. But It's not working.

Comment: The code in your question is still incorrect so until that is corrected it would be hard to say what else could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

I first also thought that is was possible to set expiration directly on the message in the post-processor, but as Tim Bish said above, this is not the intended way to do it, and the value will get reset to 0 afterward. I couldn't access to the producer directly neither to set a time to live, because this object was in library org.springframework.jms (I was following [this documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/message-expiry.html)).

One thing I could do was to set to time to live on the jmsTemplate:

```
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;

@Service
public class MyJmsServiceImpl implements MyJmsService {

    @Inject
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    private void convertAndSendToResponseQueue(String targetQueueName, String correlationid, Object message) {

        // Set time to live
        jmsTemplate.setExplicitQosEnabled(true);
        jmsTemplate.setTimeToLive(5000);
        
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(targetQueueName, message, new JmsResponsePostProcessor(correlationid));
    }

}
```